# Meaning of "AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute tk"?

Tags: python, tkinter

What does the following error message mean?

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that in your code some where you are calling

```
x.tk
```

and `x` is `None` (`NoneType`).

`x` should have been an object that is assumed to have an attribute `tk`.

To solve this problem, you can check out where you are obtaining `x` and see why it is not returning an appropriate object.

Answer (score 11):

I have had this problem but found the solution. This problem arises when you declare the variable before you make an instance of Tk().

For example, this will bring the error

```
count = IntVar()
....
....
app = Tk()
```

Solution!! Make the declarations after creating a tkinter application window

```
app = Tk()
....
count = IntVar()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for fixing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means that variable to the left of `.tk` is `None`.