# Creating, updating and reading dictionaries of stringvars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I'm working on a dice roller using a tkinter GUI. It has columns for various types of dice, and rows for the number of dice rolled. There are ~120 labels that need to be updated every time the dice are re-rolled.

I'm trying to use multi-level dictionaries containing StringVars to refresh the labels, as to avoid having to define each StringVar individually.

Currently all it does is say

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'

Here's the relevant code:

```
from random import randint

results = MultiLevelDictClass()

def roll_dice(num,die):
    result = 0
    for dice in range(0,num,1):
        result += randint(1,die)
    return result

def refresh(*args):
    for dice in [2,4,6,8,10,12,20]:
        for num in range(1,21,1):
            results[dice][num] = StringVar()
            results[dice][num].set(str(roll_dice(num,dice)))

refresh()
```

I know the general response to n-level dictionaries is negative, but the question applies to 1-level dictionaries as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3966491/2276527

Comment: @shaktimaan Thanks :), I guess I was just asking the wrong question.

Comment: What does the `Onion` class have to do with this question?

Comment: @Ourous: just be aware that the real answer to the problem is not the selected answer to that question, but rather the one related to creating an instance of `Tk` first.

Comment: @BryanOakley: you could have provided [the link to @ Holy Genius's answer directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19165597/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your root window *before* creating the StringVars.