# Python class returns AttributeError when trying to assign variable

Tags: python, class, tkinter, attributeerror

I'm having trouble with a REALLY simple class:

```
class LanguageFile:
    def __init__(self, cont):
        print(cont)
        self.var = StringVar()
        #(self.var).set(cont)
        #print(self.var)
```

`self.var = StringVar()` is already giving me a nice error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'.
```

I've tried everything I could think of but nothing worked so far. The thing that confuses me the most is that another class with basically exactly the same construction works just fine:

```
class Spinboxes(Spinbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.var = IntVar()
        Spinbox.__init__(self, master, textvariable = self.var,
                         from_ = 0, to = 100, command = crossover)
        self.config(width = "4")
        self.bind("<Return>", update_config)
```

What is difference between these two classes?

Comment: There must be more to the code that you're not showing, since `tk` doesn't appear in your code at all.

Comment: @BrenBarn The tag `tkinter` implies it but I agree that the OP should have posted the `import` statement...

Comment: If you had searched for the exact error message on stackoverflow, the first result has an answer to the problem.

Comment: Yes, the code is about 800 lines long and I tried to post only the relevant part. It appears that replacing the initializing line worked well, but how is it connected to tkinter at all?

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966475/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-tk I found it some time ago already, but couldn't understand how I could mend my code with that info.

Comment: Yes. The answer with the most votes is most likely the solution to your problem.

Comment: Shoot, I only noticed the "right" answer with the green tick next to it. I'll try and be more attentive next time. :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize tkinter by calling [`Tk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#Tkinter.Tk) first:

```
from Tkinter import StringVar, Tk

class LanguageFile:
    def __init__(self, cont):
        Tk()
        print(cont)
        self.var = StringVar()
```

Comment: Um, now that you mentioned tkinter I solved the problem by replacing the initializing line:
`str01 = LanguageFile(strings[0])`. (it was initially placed before tkinter GUI, but now I placed it far below).
However I don't quite understand how is that connected to tkinter at all?